# Is it possible/desirable to have a 'master', 'test' and 'develop' branch when using git-flow?

Tags: git, git-flow, git-workflow

I am currently working on a project where we are in the process of migrating to Git. We are trying to figure out what workflow to use. We are quite keen on git-flow, but have an issue.

As I understand git-flow, developers create `feature` branches off of `develop`, once they are done with a particular `feature` branch, the code gets merged into `develop`. When we want to release to live, `develop` is then merged into `master`. In our case, `develop` will be what is currently deployed to our **Dev** environment while `master` will be what is currently **Live**. This is all well and good.

**The thing**

The thing is that we have another environment that we need to deploy to before **Live**, ie. **Test**. We want to have a `test` branch that will always represent what is currently deployed to **Test**.

This how we envision this working:

1. Developers work in `feature` branches, that are merged into `develop`, which get deployed to **Dev**.
2. When we are ready to promote to **Test**, `develop` is merged into `test` and taken to **Test**.
3. Once all is signed off in **Test**, we merge `test` into `master` and take that **Live**.

**My Questions**

1. Is this possible with git-flow, if so, how?
2. Should we even be doing this?
3. How else could this be achieved?

Comment: Test isn't necessary though.  You deploy develop to a staging site and it gets signed off.  When that happens you merge develop into master and push master.  If `test` just mirrors `develop` then there's not much point in having `test` I'd have thought?

Comment: It does provide value to us, Dev is used for all new features that are developed, where developers can ensure that their changes are integrated correctly. Whereas Test is the environment where testers do their testing. The two are separated due to the fact that we deploy to Dev whenever a new feature is merged, and this hinders the testers as a result of the environment constantly going down. We deploy to Test less regularly so as to keep the environment stable for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

git-flow has the concept of `release` branches that you can use for that purpose.

The fact is that in git-flow, `develop` isn’t *simply* merged into `master`. You create first a `release` branch where you prepare for the live version, test it, and make last minute bug fixes before merging it to `master`, i.e. shipping it live.

When a `release` is closed it is also merged back into `develop`, so you’ll have all the fixes done while testing back into your main development branch.

> Release branches support preparation of a new production release. They allow for last-minute dotting of i’s and crossing t’s. Furthermore, they allow for minor bug fixes and preparing meta-data for a release (version number, build dates, etc.).
>
> — [A successful Git branching model » nvie.com](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)

Comment: This could definitely work. If we promote to **Test** multiple times before we go to **Live**, I assume we just take what is in `develop` and merge it into the `release` branch each time?

Comment: @KernelKoder yes, I think that would work fine although you must be somewhat careful to not smash bug fixes in the `release` branch. I can see the use case of phased testing of new features while they become ready, in the process of making a release, but I’ve personally never done it that way. Bear in mind that bug fixing of the version in **Test** (e.g. clearing a bug that is blocking the tests) should be done directly in the `release` branch, to more easily track the _nature_ of that commit, so you must take care to merge them back into `develop` before pulling new features from there.

Comment: @KernelKoder so in summary, i think if you take the “rules” of the `release` branch more to the letter, then you should probably first close the `release` branch manually and merge it back to `develop` (but not `master`, as if _cancelling_ the release) and then open a new `release` with the new features to test… but in practice I’m not too “purist” in my usage of git-flow and as long as you understand the constraints (e.g. a `release` without _any_ bug fix vs. one with some bug fixes) you should be fine applying the approach most suitable for each scenario.

Comment: @HugoFerreira What is the point of `develop` in this workflow? Why not simply checkout from `master` into a new `release` branch? 

(it seems that `develop` here is merely mirroring `master`).

Comment: @juanpazos in the `git-flow` approach the purpose of `develop` is to collect and base new feature branches being developed. Branch `master` is supposed to have only the commits that represent a live release. So, while a `release` is being worked on, `develop` would continue to receive the new features to be part of future release, while `master` would only change after the release branch is closed.

Comment: Quick comment and update about `git-flow`: this answer was in 2015, a time when I was working with packaged software (something people must download and install). I still believe `git-flow` can be a good approach for this type of used case. — Since then though, I've been working with web based software and let me be very emphatic: `git-flow` is a awful fit for that. In Web software there's always only one version live for *everyone*. You'll be much better of ditching the overhead and going with some flavour of https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com